Properly archive a web page for future use
I've already looked at a lot of the existing archiving tools, yet I have not found any one which does the following:

Load the page with JavaScript enabled
Save the DOM to a single file and embed all its resources (css, images)
Be accessible through a CLI

So far I've found tools that either support no JavaScript at all (WARC) or proceed to embed the JavaScript into the file (SingleFileCli).
I've found a Firefox addon that does what I want, however I woudln't know how to hook it up to a containerized CLI for automation.
